# Update Closed Opportunity Owner when validation rules/triggers otherwise prevent changes to closed Oppos

Tags: trigger, profile, user, system

**Scenario :** 
If I update Account Owner then I want all its Opportunity Owner should be updated with the same, irrespective of its stage(Closed/Open). I want the new Owner Updations to be made on Opportunity.

**Issue :**
Oportunities get locked when they are closed hence trigger may not change its owner. But the requirement is to update Opp owner with its account owner even though its closed.

There is an exceptional case where in System Admin can update Opportunity even when its closed. But Trigger always runs with current users(System Admin or Non System Admin) context. 
Is there any way to make trigger always run with System Admin Users context?Please help

Tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this awesome link and solution for the my problem !!!!

http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/salesforce-triggers-updating-restricted-records

Fire one WF rule on your field update, which will update field and also Re-evaluate WF on Field Change, and will run our Trigger in Default User Context of WF rule i.e. System Administrator Profile user, Now we will not face any issue updating an Opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the trigger as a class, you *might* be able to do this by adding the `without sharing` key word to the class, in which case the class *might* run `without sharing` as opposed to having the sharing of the current user enforced.

**Disclaimer:** I've not tried this, so you'll want to test this yourself to see if it will work for you. The major caveat being the following from the Apex documentation below in that I don't know whether it will apply when the class is called from a trigger context.

- The sharing setting of the class where the method is defined is applied, not of the class where the method is called. For example, if a method is defined in a class declared with with sharing is called by a class declared with without sharing, the method will execute with sharing rules enforced.

Comment: Hi, I think accepted solution link told that , this "without sharing" will cause some issue, though I haven't tried it yet, but I found accepted solution more suitable. Thank You !